# Show that a double integral of $f$ exists on the closed unit square

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Suppose $f$ is defined in the square $S=\{(x,y) | 0 \leq x \leq 1, 0 \leq y \leq 1\}$ by 
     \begin{cases}
       1 &\quad\text{if x is irrational}\\
       4y^3 &\quad\text{if x is rational}\\
     \end{cases}

a)    Show $\int_0^1 \! [\int_0^1 \! f(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}y ] \, \mathrm{d}x$ exists and is equal to $1$

b)    Show that $\int_S \! f(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}V$ does not exist.

This is the generalized Riemann integral. I know that f takes on the values $1$ and $4y^3$ within every interval in every subdivision of $S$. Honestly, that's about all I know.

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with this, but the integral over an interval is equal to the integral over that same interval with countably many points removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part follows by evaluating the inner integral for $x$ rational and irrational separately which yields 1. This is integrable on $[0,1]$.

For the second, take any rectangle $R=[x_1,x_2]\times [y_1,y_2] \subset [0,1]^2$.

It is clear that $\sup_{(x,y) \in R} f(x,y) = \max(1, 4y_2^3)$ and
$\inf_{(x,y) \in R} f(x,y) = \min(1, 4y_1^3)$.

Note that the functions $\phi_1(x,y) = \max(1,4y^3)$, $\phi_2(x,y) = \min(1,4 y^3)$ are integrable
on $[0,1]^2$  since they are continuous. It is easy to see that
$\int \phi_1 > 1 > \int  \phi_2$.

From the above, we see that for any
partition $P$ of $[0,1]^2$ we have
$U(f,P) = U(\phi_1,P)$, $L(f,P) = L(\phi_2,P)$, so
it follows that $\inf_P U(f,P) = \inf_P U(\phi_1,P) = \inf \phi_1 > 1$ and
$\sup_P L(f,P) = \sup_P U(\phi_2,P) = \sup \phi_2 < 1$, and so
$f$ is not integrable.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one,  you are holding x fixed and evaluating it as a single function of y. Note that if x is rational, then $\int _0 ^1 f(x,y)dy=\int _0 ^1 1\cdot dy=1$.  Likewise if x is irrational, we have $\int _0 ^1 f(x,y)dy=\int _0 ^1 4y^3dy=1.$  So, the inner integral evaluates to be 1 as we hold x fixed.  Thus the nested integral simplifies to $\int _0 ^1 dx=1$

However,  if we don't do it nested,  then you can show the set of discontinuities of $f$ is of measure greater than 0,  thus is not riemann integrable.  (Equivalently, you can show that you can never get a lower sum and upper sum to be within a given $\epsilon$ due to density as you noted)

Comment: I'm not sure if I "know" the anti-derivative definition of the integral yet. Is there a way to prove that the double integral exists using only the summation definition?

Comment: Not sure,  I haven't worked with that definition in a while.

Answer (score 0):

The first part is neatly addressed by another answer. For the second part, show that if you take a uniform subdivision into $n^2$ smaller rectangular squares of side length $1/n$, then when $y$ is close enough to $0$ the upper integral and lower integral obtained from the subdivision are not equal, and in fact are different by at least some constant amount.